# hexo change folder structure when generate static files

Tags: structure, directory, markdown, hexo

First of all, thanks Hexo. Here is my question:

I set `post_asset_folder` to `true` in the Hexo configuration file. Then I run:

`$ hexo new first`.

then:

`$ ls source/_posts/`

> first/ first.md hello-world.md

I added a pic named `pic.png` into `source/_posts/first` and wrote something in `source/_posts/first.md` like the following:

```
title: first

date: 2015-06-16 13:42:29

tags:

---

picture blow ^_^

![pic](first/pic.png)
```

Then:

`$ hexo g`

`$ hexo s`

I open `http://0.0.0.0:4000/`, but i coundn't see the content of `pic.png`.

I checked the folder `public/2015/06/16/first/`. I found there is some diffrience between folder `public/2015/06/16/` and folder `source/_posts/`.

1. structure of folder `public/2015/06/16/`

```
.
└── public/2015/06/16/
    ├── first
    │   ├── pic.png
    │   └── first.md
    └── hello-world
        └── hello-world.md
```

2. structure of folder `source/_posts/`

```
.
└── source/_posts/
    ├── first
    │   ├── first
    │   │   └── pic.png
    │   └── first.md
    └── hello-world
        └── hello-world.md
```

How can i unify the path format that i could get same path in `markdowm` and `index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

You can (sadly) not display an image in your markdown editor of choice **and** the rendered HTML file. To make it work in in the rendered version, you have to address it like this: `![](cat.jpg)`.

1. Set `post_asset_folder: true` in `_config.yml`
2. Create new post with `hexo new post "Some New Post"`
3. Place image in `source/_posts/Some-New-Post/`, e.g. `source/_posts/Some-New-Post/cat.jpg`
4. Display image in post with `![](cat.jpg)`

Answer (score 0):

in your post, just use **pic.png**, but not **first/pic.png**

hexo will put the files in asset folder with html file together

Comment: I will write *first/pic.png* in markdowm file and modify it to *pic.png* by this way. I hope a way that progress the thing easier like let hexo generate same folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to create post with photos. Make that `post_assets_folder` is set to `true` and follow these steps :
1. Run `hexo new post "YOUR TITLE"` (a folder `YOUR-TITLE` and a file `YOUR-TITLE.md` are created in `source/_posts`)
2. Place your photos in `source/_posts/YOUR-TITLE` folder
3. To link photos in a post, you have to use relative url, so your url will be directly the title of your photos (e.g: `pic.png`)

Comment: My step is same to yours. The third step , I wrote `first/pic.png` in md file. And it didn't work like i said.

Comment: Can you show me again the structure of `source/_posts` because I think you did a mistake in your post. a folder can't not contains a subfolder (for photos) and its post (.md file) like you wrote.

Comment: see my comment whitch @ you.

Comment: thanks for your help, I have found solution, I store image in third part plaform.

Answer (score 0):

The directory structure in the question is incorrect.

Here are my steps:

1. create a post:

   ```
   hexo new first
   ```
2. modify the post' Markdown file:

   ```
   vim source/_post/first.md
   ```

   content of `first.md`:

   ```
   title: first

   date: 2015-06-16 13:42:29

   tags:

   ---

   picture blow ^_^

   ![pic](first/pic.png)
   ```
3. add image `pic.png` to the `source/_post/first` folder
4. now the structure of `source` directory looks like this:

   ```
   - source
       `- _posts/
           `- first
               `pic.png
           `- first.md
           `- hello-world.md
   ```
5. run `hexo g && hexo s`
6. open `http://0.0.0.0` in a browser; note that the `pic.png` is not shown
7. the `public` directory looks like this:

   ```
   - public
       `- 2015
           `- 06
               `- 16
                   `- first
                       `- index.html
                       `- pic.png
                   `- hello-world
                       `- index.html
   ```

From there you can see that the `pic.png` file was moved from the subdirectory `first/first` to `first`.

So in order to make it work, you need to refer to the file relative to the post directory (`first`, e.g. `{% asset_img 'pic.png' %}` should do the trick).

Answer (score 0):

in hexo 3 the recommended way to reference a asset image is by tag plugin, rather than markdown. Check the [docs](https://hexo.io/docs/asset-folders.html)

```
{% asset_img "fudan-advanced-math-01-01.PNG"%} 
![](fudan-advanced-math-01-01.PNG) // doesn't work well
```